# Replace string in XML file with awk/sed with string from another file

Tags: xml, linux, awk, sed

Sorry for the long/weird title but I'm stuck on a problem I have. I have this XML file:

```
</member>
     <member>
      <name>TransactionID</name>
      <value><string>123456789123456</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>Number</name>
      <value><string>765101293</string></value>
     </member>
```

There, I have to replace the "765101293" with another value from another file, file2:

```
765003448
765885388
764034143
784478101
762568592
769765134
767200702
769550613
784914007
762333840
```

So, the XML file will change at each new string from file2. I am not sure how to do this. I am thinking of first processing file2 with awk and then a pipe feeding into sed:

Code:

```
#! /bin/bash -f

var=`awk -F,"\n" '{print $0}' "$1"`
sed -i "/7[0-9]{8}/c\$var/" "$2"
```

So, I would like to update my XML file (Update.xml) with the data from file2. For the first line of file2, I will have to update the existing XML: instead of "765101293" i'll put the first line of file2 > 765003448. Then I'll move the xml somewhere else, and then I'll pass to the next line on file2. Repeat the process for all lines of file2. The two variables $1 and $2 I used when I run my script like this: ./script.sh file2 Update.xml.

Could anyone help me out?

EDIT:

Here is my full xml file:

```
<methodCall>
 <methodName>UpdateOffer</methodName>
 <params>
  <param>
   <value>
    <struct>
     <member>
      <name>offerID</name>
      <value><i4>19</i4></value>
     </member>
     <member>
<name>startDate</name>
<value><dateTime.iso8601>20151028T14:11:00+0200</dateTime.iso8601></value>
</member>
     <member>
      <name>offerType</name>
      <value><i4>0</i4></value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originHostName</name>
      <value><string>TEST</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originNodeType</name>
      <value><string>Prepaid</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>originOperatorID</name>
      <value><string>operator</string></value>
     </member>
<member><name>originTimeStamp</name>
<value><dateTime.iso8601>20151028T14:16:36+0200</dateTime.iso8601></value>
</member>
     <member>
      <name>originTransactionID</name>
      <value><string>123456789123456</string></value>
     </member>
     <member>
      <name>subscriberNumber</name>
      <value><string>765101293</string></value>
     </member>
    </struct>
   </value>
  </param>
 </params>
</methodCall>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an XML parser and perhaps XSLT?

Comment: Requirement is to use sed/awk, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{nums[NR]=$0;next} sub(/>7[0-9]{8}</,">"nums[i+1]"<"){i++}' file2 Update.xml
```

but it's hard to guess given the small sample XML file input/output in your question.

Please remember this:

1. Every time you write a loop in shell to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.
2. A shell is an environment from which to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. I'll give more details about what I want it to do. I want to replace the string "76.." from this block <name>subscriberNumber</name>
      <value><string>765101293</string></value>
with values from file2. Then, the xml will be copied somewhere else and  
the next value should be put there. For example, this will be the first iteration:
<name>subscriberNumber</name>
      <value><string>765003448</string></value>; the second one:
<name>subscriberNumber</name>
      <value><string>765885388</string></value>
And so on; the xml will be overwritten everytime

Comment: Don't try to put formatted text in a question because you can't. Edit your question to show any necessary details that you forgot. Having said that, the script I posted will do exactly what you want without wasting a ton of time having to open/close the file for every change. Did you try it? If it didn't do what you want then state in what way. Just saying "this does not work" is completely useless in trying to solve the problem.