# Bash: replace matching regex with nth line from another file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have two files.

File one is a TXT and contains strings, one per line.

File two is a XML with several entries like this:

```
<data name="Btn:Cancel" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Cancel</value>
    <comment>Original English: Cancel</comment>
  </data>
```

I need to replace the VALUE value in the XML file with the corresponding string from file one: So the first occurrence of VALUE would be replaced by the first line from the file one, the second occurrence of VALUE in the XML file would be replaced by the second line from file one, and so on.

I've tried several things (basically using sed) and my last shot was

```
while read line           
do
    echo $count
    echo $line
    sed "s_<value>.*</value>_<value>$line</value>_$count" file.xml > results.xml
    ((count++))
done < file.txt
```

But it does nothing on the results.xml file :(

Comment: Initialize count to 1 in your script, but i dont think that will work, as sed works line for line. There is at most  one value per line. You must first squash the whole xml into one line. Can you try it with an one-line xml? And change the `.*` to `.*?`. Also use `-i` as napnac suggested.

Comment: I tried this: tr '\n' '^' < file.xml > temp.txt
but no joy either...

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35359144/1745001.

Comment: @EdMorton indeed, both look the same and I haven't seen this one. However, I understand the other guy wants to replace the same XML over and over again, while I have a XML file with lots of data that I want replaced. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are wrong. Your problem is exactly the same as the other one with exactly the same solution - read the TXT file into an array and then replace each target string in the XML file with the array contents using an incrementing index. I posted my answer from that question here, tweaked to match your specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your script like this

```
count=1
# test.xml is your file
cat test.xml | tr "\n" "\t" > test2.xml
while read line
do
    echo $count
    echo $line
    sed -i " s_<value>[^<]*</value>_<value>$line</value>_${count}; " test2.xml
    ((count++))
done < file.txt
cat test2.xml | tr "\t" "\n" >test3.xml
```

- initialize count
- different regex (`[^>]*`)
- use tr to transform the test.xml into a single long line that the `sed s` command with the `number flag` can work on
- use another tr to transform the long line back

Comment: This is what I ended up using, with some other changes like starting at an arbitrary entry. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/<value>/=' file.xml |
sed 'R file.txt' | 
sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1s#<value>[^<]*#<value>\2#/' |
sed -f - file.xml > file1.xml
```

This solution: finds the line number of each `<value>` line in the xml file. Then appends the value from the txt file to each line number. Combines the two into a sed instruction with the address and the value for each `<value>`. Then applies the generated sed commands against the xml file to produce the results.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using awk:

```
awk '/<value>.*<\/value>/{getline newval<"file.txt";sub(/[^>]*<\/value>/,newval"</value>")}1' file.xml
```

Or, a bit more verbose:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# If we match the <value></value> line
/<value>.*<\/value>/ {

    # Read next line from txt file
    getline newval < "file.txt"

    # Substitute value between tags
    sub(/[^>]*<\/value>/, newval "</value>")
}

# For all lines: print
{ print }
```

As a good citizen, I'll mention that parsing XML with tools other than dedicated XML parsers is generally not a good idea. Command line XML parsing can be done using, e.g.,

- [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)
- [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For this job specifically the XML was super consistent and I was confident about using this approach (I had 1 exception out of more than 4k values to deal with).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `--in-place` (or `-i`) argument of the sed command, like this :

`sed -i 's/hello/test/' your_file`

This will modify the file.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it modifies the file, but EVERY single occurrence of <value>.*</value> gets replaced by the first line of the TXT file :(

Comment: Not sure that sed is what you should use, take a look at this : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181771/how-to-replace-only-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-pattern-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a real programming language, such as Perl. For example:

```
perl -e ' use warnings;
          use strict;

          open my $new_values_fh, "<", "file.txt" or die;

          while (<>) {
              if (m{<value>}) {
                  my $new_value = <$new_values_fh>; chomp $new_value;
                  s{(<value>).*?(</value>)}{$1$new_value$2};
              }
              print;
          }
        ' < file.xml > results.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{nums[NR]=$0;next} sub(/<value>.*<\/value>/,"<value>"nums[i+1]"</value>"){i++}' file.txt file.xml
```

but it's hard to guess given the small sample XML input file in your question and no associated TXT file so we have nothing to test against.

Please remember this:

1. Every time you write a loop in shell to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.
2. A shell is an environment from which to manipulate files and processes and sequence calls to tools. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.