# How to use notepad++ to replace values from another file one at a time

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-search

I have a text file (fileA) that has the same block of text 100 times (approx)

I also have a text file (fileB) that has 100 (approx) values, one per line.

I want to search fileA, and each time pattern is found, replace pattern with the next line of fileB, i.e. replace the first occurence of pattern with the first line of fileB, the second occurence with the second line of fileB etc.

Comment: Must it be notepad++? How about the traditional Unix suite of text processing tools, or perl?

Comment: no, I could use unix based tool like sed, awk, grep. notepad macros and scripts  seemed like a good entry point.

Comment: I guess I will now use this! :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397224/bash-replace-matching-regex-with-nth-line-from-another-file
I widened my search thanks to you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: replace matching regex with nth line from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397224/bash-replace-matching-regex-with-nth-line-from-another-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a little on other tools for this problem and came upon this answer.

[Bash: replace matching regex with nth line from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397224/bash-replace-matching-regex-with-nth-line-from-another-file)

This worked for me, so this is what I went with.

Answer (score 0):

Let me pseudo-code what I would do in, say, Perl:

```
let subst_file = open(cmd-line arg 1) for reading, or exit with error
while line = line from stdin
  if pattern contained in line:
    replace_pattern = read next line from subst_file
    replace_line = regexp_replace(line, pattern, replace_pattern)
    output replace_line
  else:
    output line
```

And leave it to others or your own research for the rest. For example the while loop in perl would be: `while (my $line = <STDIN>) { ... }`